# WooCommerce - remove line breaks without editing template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding increment buttons on product page around quantity div, which contains quantity input field. I hook my button-generating functions `create_button_before` and `create_button_after`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'create_button_before' );        
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'create_button_after' );
```

This works great apart from one thing. I would like the buttons to be adjacent without space to quantity div as inline-block elements. Unfortunately inline-block in CSS separates elements with line breaks styled as white spaces.

On product page there is no way I can apply regular CSS hack to make parent element's font-size 0 (space would have 0 width) and explicitly state font-size of all children. It's because there is no constant element structure of ancestors - it changes based on whether product is single, variable, grouped etc. Maybe I would somehow be able to handle all cases, but maintenance-wise it would be worse than overriding templates.

Is there any way I could eliminate line breaks after my first button and before second button with PHP, while not overriding template?

EDIT: I found out that as CSS solution, `display: block` and `float: left` will work properly, assuming that I add left margin to Add to cart button which is next to my buttons. I still would like to know if I can achieve this through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

How about in your 'create button' functions, when creating the button html, include inline styling in your button?

```
style="display:block; float:left"
```

If this style is meant to be applied to a parent container, then include `<style></style>` on your page to override that container with this style?

Comment: This is exactly what I found out and put in "EDIT" of my original post. For now I will stick with it, though I would prefer if I could simply remove these line breaks, so I don't need to care about aligning elements after my buttons (Add to cart button) or trying to center my floated elements within container.